# Можно ли переделать объект типа Color в объект типа Brush(Brushes) в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть класс **DrawingColorPanel** наследуемый от класса **Panel**.
В нем я переписываю метод *onPaint*:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 0, 0, 24, 24);
   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 24, 24);
}
```

Заковырка в том что бы моему прямоугольнику (FillRectangle) присваивался цвет из объекта penColorGlobal типа **Color**.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(penColorGlobal, 0, 0, 24, 24);
   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 24, 24);
}
```

Но я не могу этого сделать потому что перегруженные методы FillRectanlge() не предусматривают тип Color.

Вопрос: возможно ли переделать объект penColorGlobal  в тип **Brush(Brushes)** и если да то как? Если есть другие методы как это сделать напишите пожалуйста :)
Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   Brush br = new SolidBrush(penColorGlobal);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, 24, 24);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это то что мне было нужно)